# How to cut data inside GeoJSON polygon from adjacent ASCII grid files?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geojson, esri-ascii-raster

I have a set of Digital Terrain Model ASCII grid files; they're the output of a LIDAR survey over our city, and so cover adjacent areas. Now I need to "cut" a polygon out of these files; this polygon is in GeoJSON format and can overlap across more than one of these DTM files.

Then the cut area should be put into a new ASCII grid file, because it needs to be passed to an existing program our team created, with the area outside the polygon.

Here is a diagram to give a more visual description.

[image: Magic needed!]

How can I execute this operation?

I have GDAL installed, and I have admin rights, so I can install any software I need. Of course it would be better if it was Open Source, but the most important things is that I will have to automate this operation next, so something that works from the command line or has a Python API would be ideal for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing this might work.

1) Create a virtual mosaic from all your source files

```
gdalbuildvrt mosaic.vrt *.asc
```

2) Use gdalwarp and crop the mosaic to cutline

`gdalwarp -of [your format] -cutline your_geojson.json -crop_to_cutline mosaic.vrt cropped_output.[ext]`.

You may need to give also the layer name for the GeoJSON cutline which is always "OGRGeoJSON".

Comment: This did work to generate GeoTIFFs and a few other files. Thanks! However, I can't generate the Ascii grid files I need. I tried using **-of AAIGrid** which is the type _gdalinfo_ gives me for the source files, but I get a message saying that it's not recognized.